# Tag link with parameters from snippet

Tags: modx-revolution

How can I add parameter to link from snippet?

[[~34? &p=`[[!getUrlParam? &name=`p`&int=`1`]]`]]

This is not working (none snippet don`t work). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use makeUrl:

http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/other-development-resources/class-reference/modx/modx.makeurl

// snippet getUrlParam

// if you have to get a url param:
$param = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;

$url = $modx->makeUrl(34,'',array('p' => $param));

return $url;

Comment: Thank you. I did it as you suggest but I am curious why my code do not work?

Comment: it didn't work because your syntax was incorrect, [[~34]]?p=[[!getUrlParam? &whatever=`whatever`]] would have been the correct syntax. (if it worked for you, you should mark it as the correct answer)

Comment: This solution is nice, thank you. But I think my syntax is correct http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources#Resources-URLParametersforResourceTags It works fine without snippet e.g.[[~34? &p=[[+whatever]]]]

Comment: Huh - I had not see it done that way before! Modx may not process snippets inside the ~url tags. not sure what order it parses the doc in, but you could test it with a simple snippet: return '123'; or even see if it will fetch the contents of a chunk. [though it would be 'just to see' at this point]